# How to plot the graph between w and phi with given a equation using MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, plot, using

> tanh(w/2 sqrt(β^2 −k^2εd) =−εd /εm sqrt((β^2−k^2εm)/(β^2−k^2εd))

where w is betweem 50 to 250.

> β=phi/d
>
> d=500nanometer
>
> k^2=9.85*10^(-5)
>
> εd=1
>
> εm=-17.2355+0.498i(complex number)

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
w=50:0.0001:250;
f= sin(w);
plot(w,f);
```

now define f as you want too.

check this out as well

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html